# Finding a unique shared point between all possible tangent planes of the function $z = xf\left(\frac{x}{y} \right)$ - Unsatisfying answer in prev post

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I've been given a question and I feel like I'm either way off trail or right at the end. 
note- the question was asked (poorly) by someone two years ago, got closed and had no satisfying response. links given to other questions similar to this one in the responses have been broken.  
**the question**

- $f(t)$ has a derivative for every $t$
- $z$ is defined as $z = xf\left(\frac{x}{y} \right)$ for every $t$. $(y \neq 0)$

*show all planes tangent tangent to $z$ share a singular point - find it*

 **my progress so far**

I started by defining $\tilde{f}=xf\left(\frac{x}{y} \right)$ and finding it's partial derivatives. I also defined $t(x,y) = \frac{x}{y}$
$$\frac{\partial{\tilde{f}}}{\partial{x}} = f_t'(t) *t + f(t)$$
$$\frac{\partial{\tilde{f}}}{\partial{y}} = f_t'(t) * (-t^2)$$
I then placed it into the formula for tangent plane $$z-z_0 =\frac{\partial{\tilde{f}}}{\partial{x}}(x-x_0) + \frac{\partial{\tilde{f}}}{\partial{y}}(y-y_0)$$

 I then saw some stuff cancelled each other out - I also used the fact that $t*y=x$ - I also used that for $t * y_0 = x_0$. AND I've used the fact that $z = xf\left(\frac{x}{y} \right)$ - which I've also used in this for: $z_0 = x_0f\left(\frac{x_0}{y_0} \right)$

The final result:
$$f'_t *t^2=0$$
Am I right? did I overcomplicate it? what do I need to do from here?

 - note - someone in my class said the point should be $(0,0,0)$ but I don't know if he's right.